# Would you be happy to welcome Whonix GNU/Linux users on unix.se?

Tags: discussion, scope

Speaking as a maintainer of [Whonix GNU/Linux](https://www.whonix.org) which is a derivative of Debian GNU/Linux. Its focus is on anonymity/Tor.

Having a dedicated user support forum for Whonix and teaching Windows users who use a Debian derivative for the first time in a virtual machine the most basic things eats up a lot time. And is a lot duplicate effort. Many of those questions can probably be answered using the search function of this website.

For basic questions, such as "how to use apt-get", "how to install a package", I would like to recommend Whonix's users to use unix.stackexchange.com. And also recommend, if they open a new question, adding the tag "whonix" (if that is ok).

For general Tor/anonymity questions I would like to recommend Whonix's users to use tor.stackexchange.com (after asking tor.se if that goes okay as well).

whonix.org's own forum would stay open for questions not suited for the stackexchange format (opinion based, feedback, discussion).

I would myself [subscribe](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/subscribe-to-tags-via-emai/) to questions having the tag "whonix", and answer if no one else was faster and/or comment if I feel necessary.

Would you be happy to welcome Whonix GNU/Linux users on unix.se?

Comment: If it's a linux derivative I don't see any problem...

Comment: sounds fine to me

Comment: I love this, but I want to make sure it doesn't turn into Ask Ubuntu (where questions with "meat" are way overrun with newbie questions that may be poorly formulated, misguided, super localized, etc). I suspect this won't be a problem (since I'm assuming that the Whonix userbase is relatively small, at least compared to Ubuntu), but I just want to mention it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Anything that is Unix or Unix-like is welcome here.

Answer (score 10):

> Having a dedicated user support forum for Whonix and teaching Windows users who use a Debian derivative for the first time in a virtual machine the most basic things eats up a lot time.

This is the place...I'm also part of the [raspberry pi S.E. site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), and virtually all pi's run some flavour of linux; there are many people there who are also *"Windows users who use a Debian derivative for the first time"*.  I don't think the dedicated pi site is a bad thing, but **most** of the questions there would get much better treatment here because they are really general linux questions.

Point being it is good you have noticed this overlap before you created your own forum.

A `whonix` tag is totally appropriate and your community can use that to keep up with each other.